# Temporarily disable one gesture recognizer while another is firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I have a `UITableView` that I want to scroll itself naturally. However I have my own gesture recognizer attached to it as well that is recognized simulataneously (via returning `YES` from `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`).

After a certain point computed by my gesture handler, I want to *temporarily stop* the table view from handling the gesture changes of its own underlying gesture. This is because at this point I am resizing the table view and I don't want it to scroll while this is happening (but remain scrolled to the position it was in when the resizing started to take effect).

I've tried recording the other gesture recognizer in `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`, which seems to identify the right one as it is showing up as `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`. However nothing I do to that recognizer inside my own handler seems to have any effect.

One would think that setting `otherRecognizer.enabled = NO` should do the trick, but it doesn't have any effect.

Perhaps the table view is receiving its gesture event before mine, such that disabling it at that point has no effect, but even then you would think that it would be disabled on the next change event, but that's not the case either.

I'm stumped. How do I temporarily block the table view from receiving/processing gestures without canceling the gesture entirely?

**Update:**

When I log `otherRecognizer`, it appears as an object of type `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`, however its state is `Failed`. I also notice that there are in fact many calls to `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` (even multiple ones of type `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`), so perhaps I am simply recording and disabling the wrong one... but how do I figure out which is the one I want?

**Update 2:**

If I set `tableView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO` at the appropriate moment inside my own gesture handler, it get's me half way there—the table no longer scrolls once I start resizing it. However, setting it back to enabled does not re-activate the gesture and it no longer handles any further scrolling until a new gesture starts.

**Update 3:**

I ended up "solving" this by manually adjusting the scroll view's content offset during the gesture. It seems to work fine, but I'm still curious for the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

A UITableView is a UIScrollView. A UIScrollView has a `panGestureRecognizer` property. That's the gesture recognizer that responds to the user moving a finger on the table view.

However, this has nothing to do with the scroll position changing while you're resizing the table view. The user isn't doing anything - you are. So there is no gesture and nothing to recognize. If you want to control what the scroll view is doing, you need to control it *directly*. You can use UITableView methods, UIScrollView methods, and the UIScrollView delegate.

It's hard to advise further without a clearer problem statement, but it seems to me that the answer to question you *did* ask is that you're barking up the wrong tree. But perhaps not; perhaps you *are* gesturing to resize the table view and you didn't make this clear in the question? In that case, try disabling the `panGestureRecognizer`. Or, even better, just temporarily turn off all user interaction for the table view and detect this gesture elsewhere.

Comment: The resizing I am doing manually in my own gesture handler. Basically, the table view resizes as the user scrolls outside of it. However the problem is that while it is resizing it *keeps scrolling*. Since the table view is at the bottom of the window and it is resizing upwards, the table no longer appears to follow the finger but rather scrolls twice as fast as it should.

Comment: The `panGestureRecognizer` property of the table view is a step in the right direction—thanks for that! See my update 2.

Comment: I have a table view cell, where on a view inside the cell's content view I have added a pan gesture to swipe the view left and right. I want when this gesture is in progress then table view scrolling should not work and if scrolling is in progress then cell swiping should not work.